# Android outlook web Add-ins white screen problem

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

Outlook web Add-ins works on the web but does not work in outlook android app comes white screen

I installed the plugin on my mobile outlook app
I open the plugin from draft mail but the white screen is coming

Note:
Outlook web Add-ins application is running on the server

My Manifest.xml code
Are there any errors in the code below?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>e369f2e0-9fcd--9fcd--9fcd-e369f2e02dfas2</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>xxxxxxx</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>tr-TR</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="test" />
  <Description DefaultValue="test"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Images/icon64.png"/>

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.google.com" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.google.com"</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Home/Index"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <!--<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup2">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton2">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="uploadPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>

        <MobileFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="mobilefunctionFile"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
            <Group id="msgReadGroup">
              <Label resid="Tikla"/>
              <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                <Label resid="Tikla"/>
                <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon16"/>

                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon32"/>

                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon80"/>
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon80"/>
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="mobilMessageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                </Action>
              </Control>
            </Group>
          </ExtensionPoint>


          
        </MobileFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Images/icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Images/icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Images/icon80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>

        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Home/Index"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Attachment/AttachmentList"/>
        <bt:Url id="mobilMessageReadTaskPaneUrl2" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Home/Index"/>
        <bt:Url id="mobilMessageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Attachment/AttachmentList"/>
        <bt:Url id="uploadPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://x1.44.xx.xx:xxx/Attachment/AttachmentList"/>

      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxx"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Upload attachments"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Select and share files"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="tes88t"/>
        <bt:String id="Tikla" DefaultValue="tes8st"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="folder"/>

      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  

  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>







</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Can you run any other add-ins there? Are they working as expected?

Comment: other plugins are working

Comment: Do you see any console errors? Can you try this css: html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} and see if it works

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. How do I find console errors on mobile

Comment: Can you try using some these free debugging tools to debug this further?
(1) [vorlonjs](http://vorlonjs.com/documentation/#introduction) 
(2) [remotejs](https://remotejs.com/)  (A free version of TrackJS)
(3) [jsconsole](https://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging) 

or if you can share sample add-in with your code and manifest, we can also try to repro and debug this.

Comment: It fixed when https was installed thank you